# passing expression in a nested function

Tags: r

I'm trying to pass an expression in a nested series of functions. Here is a simplified example of work that I want to do:

```
require(shiny)
outterfunc <- function(a,b,expr){
  innerfunc <- function(a,b, expr){
    shiny::exprToFunction(expr,quoted = F)()
  }
  return(innerfunc(a = a+1,b= b+1, expr=expr))
}
```

I expect to get this result when I'm running following commands:

```
outterfunc(2,5,{a*b})
# 18
```

which give me error like

```
# Error in exprToFunction(expr, quoted = F)() : object 'b' not found
```

I managed to solve issue with using `eval(parse(text=paste(......` sequence, but I'm wondering is there any clean way to pass expression between nested functions.

Thank you in advance for reading this.

Comment: Where does `exprToFunction` come from? Be sure to include references to all relevant packages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for inconvenience with the `exprToFunction`. I was using this so widely that I forgot it is not the base function :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, It seems like this will work

```
outterfunc <- function(a,b,expr){
  innerfunc <- function(a,b, expr){
    ex <- eval(substitute(substitute(expr)),parent.frame())
    eval(ex, environment())
  }
  return(innerfunc(a = a+1,b= b+1, expr=expr))
}

outterfunc(2,5,{a*b})
# [1] 18
```

First you need to grab the unevaluated expression from two levels up, then you evaluate it within the current parameter value context.

Comment: Dealing with a similar nested expression problem and I never would of figured this out on my own. Thanks for sharing this solution! Can you point me towards any resources to help me better understand how/when to use nested eval/substitute calls?